# How to pull and check-out remote Git repository

Tags: windows, git, msysgit

OK, total noob question, for msysgit on Windows 7,  but I have a remote repository (on unfuddle), create on one PC, and now I want to pull it down to another PC.  I tried 'Fetch' using Git Gui, but the folder still only has a .git subfolder.  It took a while pulling it down, so I assume there is something in the repo, but how do I check it out to a working copy.  Nothing I have tried seems to work.

SOLUTION:
It's not directly in his answer, but VonC below pointed me to the unfuddle help documentation for Git, which is as terse as the Git man-pages are dense.  The follwing single command got me the working copy and local repository I needed:

```
$ git clone git@subdomain.unfuddle.com:subdomain/abbreviation.git
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the [Git documentation on Unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com/docs/git), did you declare your unfunddle repo as a remote?

```
$ cd /path/to/repository
$ git remote add unfuddle git@subdomain.unfuddle.com:subdomain/abbreviation.git
```

Try also `gitk --all`: if the fetch has succeded, you should the remote tracking branches (like `unfuddle/master`). You can then merge it to your master branch in order to finally see files in your (still empty) working tree.
You could also have done a `git pull` to combine the two steps together (fetch+merge). See this [blog post](http://blog.djmatty.com/?p=302) for illustration.

---

Actually, the OP [ProfK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8741/profk) reports a cloning issue:

> I did already have the unfuddle remote added

```
git clone git@subdomain.unfuddle.com:subdomain/abbreviation.git
```

is more suited to get a local repo with the right remote already added to it.

Comment: thanks, but I did already have the unfuddle remote added, but you reminded me about their documentation.  See me edits.

Comment: @ProfK: glad to see you did find the right command. I have included it in this answer.